# How to get open files of a subprocess?

Tags: python, linux, posix, fsync

How to get open files of a subprocess?

i opened a subprocess which generate files, i want get file descritor of these files to do fsync on them

so if i have code like this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen([
            'some_program'
])
```

the process p generate some files
i can get the process id of the subprocess using:

```
p.pid
```

but how can i get fd of these files to call flush and fsync() on them?

actually i find a utility called "lsof" (list open files)
but it is not installed or supported on my system, so i did not do further investigations on it, as i really need a standard way

thanks

Comment: I think you can find this information in the procfs, usually mounted on /dev/proc.  Further than that I don't know.

Comment: You can get a list of open file descriptors by looking in `/proc/$PID/fd/`. They are symlinks pointing to the original open files. I don't know whether `fsync` will work if you open them in another process though.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?  Even if you get the file descriptors, you certainly can't call `fsync` on them, since they don't mean anything in the parent process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each process has its own table of file descriptors. If you know that a child process has a certain file open with FD 8 (which is easy enough, just take a listing of `/proc/<pid>/fd`), when you do `fsync(8)` you are sync'ing a file of *your* process, not the child's.

The same applies to all functions that use file descriptors: `fread`, `fwrite`, `dup`, `close`...

To get the effect of `fsync`, you might call `sync` instead.

What you could do instead is implement some kind of an RPC mechanism. For example you could add a signal handler that makes the child run `fsync` on all open FDs when it receives SIGUSR1.

Comment: Do you mean to run the sync command from the shell? it flushes all files of all processes on the system which may take several seconds on a cloud hosting (where i run my program)...

Comment: No, I meant the `void sync(void)` C function from `unistd.h`. Which is basically the same thing as the `sync(1)` program.

Comment: I am using python, do you know its python counterpart or how to call it from python?

Comment: If the `sync` shell command is too slow, so is the C function. You need a different solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a packed solution, instead of going to /proc/pid/fd, an option is to use lsof of [psutils](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/)

Answer (score 1):

You can't fsync on behalf of another process. Also, you probably want flushing, not fsync. You can't flush on behalf of another process either. Rethink your requirements.